# How to create flexible connections, such as a Keyring with a few keys?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I would like to model an AR asset, like a keyring with a few keys in it. Obviously, I would like to show that it could be picked up and then because of physics, keys will naturally show up to the bottom of the ring. How could I do that in ARKit / Reality Composor / USDZ or anyway that iOS allows?

[EDIT] Andy Fedoroff perfectly answered my question about whether ARKit / Reality Composor could model a keyring with a few keys question. Are there other tools (such as Unity or UnrealEngine or Houdini) that could be used to model this kind of relationship? Will USD / USDZ support this kind of model?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now there are no physics constraints (behaviours) in RealityKit 2.0 or in Reality Composer 1.5.

However, in SceneKit you can constrain two objects with [SCNPhysicsBallSocketJoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsballsocketjoint).

```
class SCNPhysicsBallSocketJoint: SCNPhysicsBehavior
```

Test Chris Flannagan's project called [iOS-Bimini-Ring-Toss](https://github.com/ChrisFlannagan/iOS-Bimini-Ring-Toss) to find out how it works.

[image]

Comment: Very cool. Thank you. Here is Chris Flannagan's article about this project: https://whoischris.com/build-3d-chainstringrope-scenekit-swift/    Is there a tool to create this kind of model? Will Unity or UnrealEngine do that? I wonder if USDZ is a more flexible framework that supporting this kind of model and it is just Apple tools do not support it yet.

Comment: USD is Pixar's proprietary format. Unity and Unreal are capable to do this, but RealityKit is too young for now. Give it a try in 3 years, I think RK will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposal ["Rigid Body Physics in USD"](https://graphics.pixar.com/usd/docs/attachments/676942914/676942921.pdf) that supposedly solve this issue.